# Rewrite Zend Url dynamically using mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I have a URL dynamically generated in `zend Framework` as below

```
    www.mysite.com/user/newprojects/view-more/project/12
```

For id=12 the city is `hyderabad`,area name is `vst`,project name is `DSK woods`. But I would like to display the URL as

```
    www.mysite.com/hyderabad/vst/dsk-woods
```

and the other URL

```
    www.mysite.com/user/newprojects/view-more/project/13
```

For id=13 the city is `Bangalore`,area name is `white field`,project name is `My homes`. But I would like to display the URL as

```
    www.mysite.com/bangalore/white-field/my-homes
```

Like this I have many id's. each has its own dynamic webpage. For all these I get the city and area name dynamically from database and echo using php in my webpage. How do I get the city and area parameters for the url to generate dynamically using mod_rewrite and htaccess?

Comment: You don't need to use mod_rewrite, this can be done via Zend Routes (create your custom one)

Comment: but I have to do it in htaccess, I have a restriction where I can't use zend custom routing